# LinearSeqOptimized#find Reference Copy

Tags: algorithm, scala, collections

Looking at the `Scala 2.10.0`'s implementation of `LinearSeqOptimized#find` in `LinearSeqOptimized.scala`, why is it necessary to call `var these = this`?

Why couldn't **this** simply be used?

```
  override /*IterableLike*/
  def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head)) return Some(these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
    None
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you would have to have the same condition and operation out of the loop for this and then start using these.

It's much simpler to just put everyone in the same basket and do it all in the loop itself. Example:

```
def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {

  if (!this.isEmpty && p(this.head)) {
    return Some(this.head)
  }

  var these = this.tail

  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    if (p(these.head)) return Some(these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }

  None
}
```

Not very smart, as you can see.

You could also easily implement this as a `@tailrec` operation:

```
@tailrec final def find[A](p : A => Boolean) : Option[A] = {    
  if ( this.isEmpty ) {
    None
  } else {
    if ( p(this.head) ) {
      Some(this.head)
    } else {
      this.tail.find(p)
    }
  }
}
```

And it isn't done like this in Scala because tailrec calls have to be final or private.

Comment: yes, since you wouldn't get the next tail, but the current tail and it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Included a simple `tailrec` solution that might be what you were thinking.